# Картинка вместо цвета текста css

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Возможно ли с помощью каких-то способов заполнить изображением текст, вместо цвета.

Comment: Смотри в сторону `svg`

Comment: Браузеры на webkit поддерживают свойство `background-clip`, но вам, надо полагать, нужно кроссбраузерное решение.

Comment: +1 air, вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/xWNR3/2/

Comment: @brachkoff + плюс ещё один вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785015/28748

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нашел как это сделать на чистом css с помощью свойства `mix-blend-mode`. К сожалению он поддерживается [не во всех современных браузерах](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-).

```css
.text {
  background: url(https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=eab0e1b995f2c8861ea50c27af8601bb-l&n=13);
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  font-size:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Изображение внутри буквы</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает на iOS safari

Answer (score 6):

Вот способ только для для браузеров на движке webkit

```css
.block{
  background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/1/1d/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C.png) no-repeat center/cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Текст 
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Использование текста в качестве маски

Картинку ставим фоном, текст используется в качестве маски для изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другими словами мы видим картинку через вырезы в форме букв текста.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" >
<defs>
  <mask id="LetMask"  > 
  <rect 
    x="0" y="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="#black" />
     <text
      font-size="300px"
      font-family="serif"
      x="100" y="300"
      fill="white">
      Text &#9973;
     </text>
  </mask>
</defs>
 <image 
   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbuGW.jpg"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   mask="url(#LetMask)" /> 
</svg>
```

Маска состоит из двух частей: прямоугольника перекрывающего картинку на 100%  с полной непрозрачностью,- `fill="black"` и полностью прозрачным текстом `fill="white"`

Можно добавить строку, обводку текста, которая будет полупрозрачной

```
stroke="grey" stroke-width="4"
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" >
<defs>
  <mask id="LetMask"  > 
  <rect 
   x="0"
   y="0"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   fill="#black" />
    <text
     font-size="300px"
     font-family="serif"
     x="100"
     y="300"
     fill="white"
     stroke="gray"
     stroke-width="5">
     Text &#9973;
    </text>
  </mask>
</defs>
 <image 
   xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbuGW.jpg"     width="100%"
   height="100%"mask="url(#LetMask)" /> 
</svg>
```

Маску можно передвигать относительно фона

### Анимация маски

*Используем анимацию изменения размера и положение текста маски*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" >
<defs>
  <mask id="LetMask"  > 
  <rect
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="#181818" />
  <!-- Анимация размера шрифта -->
  <text
    font-size="300px"
    font-family="serif"
    x="100"
    y="300"
    fill="white">
    Text &#9973;
    
  <animate id="anSize"
   attributeName="font-size"
    begin="0s;anX.end+0.5s"
    dur="5s"
    values="1;300"
    fill="freeze" />
<!-- Анимация перемещения текста по координате "X" -->  
  <animate id="anX"
   attributeName="x"
   begin="anSize.end+0.5s"
   dur="8s"
   values="10;300;300;10;10;300;10"
   fill="freeze" /> 
    </text>
    </mask>
</defs>
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbuGW.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"mask="url(#LetMask)" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вариантов много....

Answer (score 5):

Вот еще вариант с `pattern` на `svg`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
<style>
svg{
background:transparent;
}
</style>
<pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
         width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <image xlink:href="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/trees-forest-fall-waterfall-water-nature-rocks-national-park-pond-jungle-stream-rainforest-watercourse-wasserfall-habitat-natural-environment-body-of-water-water-feature-57484.jpg" width="200" height="100" />
</pattern>
<text x="15" y="80"   stroke="none" stroke-width="11"  font-size="100px" fill="url(#pattern)" >Text</text>
</svg>
```