# Как сделать цвет - картинкой css?

Tags: css, вёрстка

как сделать что бы картинка была как цветом , как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Картинка вместо цвета текста css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784209/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос уже как-то искали. Вот актуальная [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784209/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-css) на него. В вопросе рассматривается несколько вариантов. Надеюсь найдёте нужный вам.

Comment: Спасибо большое Михаил)